# Sort JS array by value like Python

Tags: javascript, python

**NOTE: The question was fundamentally updated after first answers**

How can I do in JS an array sorting equivalent of the python code `sort(array)` or `array.sort()` (inplace), like in this example:

```
data = [
    { 'id': [2], 'other properties': ... },
    { 'id': [1,3,0,00,15], 'other properties': ... },
    { 'id': [1,0,0], 'other properties': ... },
    { 'id': [1,3,0,00,14], 'other properties': ... },
    { 'id': [1,3,0], 'other properties': ... },
]

data.sort(key = lambda e: e['id'] )


# output 
data == 
    [
        { 'id': [1, 0], 'other properties': ...},
        { 'id': [1, 0, 0], 'other properties': ...},
        { 'id': [1, 3, 0], 'other properties': ...},
        { 'id': [1, 3, 0, 0, 14], 'other properties': ...},
        { 'id': [1, 3, 0, 0, 15], 'other properties': ...},
        { 'id': [2] 'other properties': ...},
    ]
```

Comment: Did you try `data.sort()`?

Comment: I did, but I think I got too confused by the documentation. I really believed that I would need a key function to sort.

Comment: I found this question interesting regardless it's simplicity... answer below.

Answer (score 7):

So... I stumbled myself wondering how the Array's sort method works and it really looks counter intuitive to me, but maybe it's just me.

Anyway... considering my python background I decided to write a `sorted` function that tries to implement python's sorting logic.

The function return a sorted array without modifying the original.

There are two optional parameters passed as second argument in form of a `kwargs` object.

Optional parameters are:

- `reverse` - when `reverse` is `false` (the default) the sorting is ascending, in case it's `true` then the sorting is descending.
- `key` - is a `key` generator function that processes the `items` array producing keys with it's original positions and then sorts keys using simple comparison between primitives or tuple like comparison similar to python's

After sorting the key array the original array is returned ordered according to key's position in sorted output.

Source:

```
function sorted(items, kwargs={}) {
    const key = kwargs.key === undefined ? x => x : kwargs.key;
    const reverse = kwargs.reverse === undefined ? false : kwargs.reverse;
    const sortKeys = items.map((item, pos) => [key(item), pos]);
    const comparator =
        Array.isArray(sortKeys[0][0])
        ? ((left, right) => {
            for (var n = 0; n < Math.min(left.length, right.length); n++) {
                const vLeft = left[n], vRight = right[n];
                const order = vLeft == vRight ? 0 : (vLeft > vRight ? 1 : -1);
                if (order != 0) return order;
            }
            return left.length - right.length;
        })
        : ((left, right) => {
            const vLeft = left[0], vRight = right[0];
            const order = vLeft == vRight ? 0 : (vLeft > vRight ? 1 : -1);
            return order;
        });
    sortKeys.sort(comparator);
    if (reverse) sortKeys.reverse();
    return sortKeys.map((order) => items[order[1]]);
}
```

Usage examples:

```
console.log(sorted([-1, 9, -3, 4, -3, 6, 1, -7], {reverse: true}));
console.log(sorted([-1, 9, -3, 4, -3, 6, 1, -7]));
console.log(sorted(["U", "z", "Z", "f", "F", "a", "c", "d", "x"], {key: x => [x.toLowerCase(), x]}));
console.log(sorted(['-1', '9', '-3', '4', '-3', '6', '1', '-7', '11111']));
console.log(sorted(['-1', '9', '-3', '4', '-3', '6', '1', '-7', '11111'], {key: x => parseFloat(x)}));

data = [
    { 'id': [2], 'other properties': null },
    { 'id': [1,3,0,00,-15], 'other properties': null },
    { 'id': [1,-3,0,00,15], 'other properties': null },
    { 'id': [1,-3,0,00,-15], 'other properties': null },
    { 'id': [1,0,0], 'other properties': null },
    { 'id': [1,3,0,00,14], 'other properties': null },
    { 'id': [1,3,0], 'other properties': null },
]

console.log("PY asc", sorted(data, {key: x=>x.id}))

console.log("JS asc", [...data].sort(x=>x.id))

console.log("PY desc", sorted(data, {key: x=>x.id, reverse: true}))

console.log("JS desc", [...data].sort(x=>x.id).reverse())
```

Output for data provided by the original question:

```
PY asc [
  { id: [ 1, -3, 0, 0, -15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, -3, 0, 0, 15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 0, 0 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0, 0, -15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0, 0, 14 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 2 ], 'other properties': null }
]
JS asc [
  { id: [ 2 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0, 0, -15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, -3, 0, 0, 15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, -3, 0, 0, -15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 0, 0 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0, 0, 14 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0 ], 'other properties': null }
]
PY desc [
  { id: [ 2 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0, 0, 14 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0, 0, -15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 0, 0 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, -3, 0, 0, 15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, -3, 0, 0, -15 ], 'other properties': null }
]
JS desc [
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0, 0, 14 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 0, 0 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, -3, 0, 0, -15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, -3, 0, 0, 15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 1, 3, 0, 0, -15 ], 'other properties': null },
  { id: [ 2 ], 'other properties': null }
]
```

That's all folks.

Answer (score 1):

`data.sort()` will do exactly what you want
it only sorts the immediate level of the array
`data[3].sort()` will change `[1,3,0,00,14]` to `[0,00,1,14,3]`

Comment: data.sort() will do exactly what it's implemented to do, not necessarily what I want 